# perl - using backticks instead of system()

Tags: perl, system, return-value, backticks

I have a perl script that calls an other perl script by using system()

it's like:

```
my $returnval= system("perl", $path,$val1, $val2,@myarray);
```

Because system() returns only the exit status but I want the script's output I want to use backticks.

I tried something like that:

```
my $returnval = `$path`;
```

how can I add the parameters the script should receive?

how should the other perl script's return code looks like? At the moment it's like

```
exit ($myreturnedvalue);
```

(how) Is it  possible to return multiple values?

Comment: Regrettably, I do not understand the question about returning multiple values.  Would you clarify?

Comment: I want to call a script with parameters, then I want the script's output and this output, does it have to be a single value or can it be an array or two parameters like exit (x1,x2)

Comment: You can only return a piece of text (or binary data). If you want multiple values then the script you are calling needs to return a serialised data structure (space separated, JSON, XML, etc) that you parse in your Perl.

Comment: ah, okay, so I have to work on the text for extracting the information I want, thanks :)

Comment: Are you trying to have perl functions in more than file within the program, or are you struggling to understand how to use `$?` in your program?  `$output = ˋcmd arg1 arg2ˋ; $status = $?;` gets both output and status separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To go through the shell in order to move data from one perl script to another is not the best solution. You should know that backticks or `qx()` captures whatever is printed to STDOUT. Using `exit ($var)` from the other script is unlikely to be captured properly. You would need `print $var`. But don't do that.

Instead, make the other script into a module and use the subroutine directly. This is a simplistic example:

In bar.pm:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package bar;  # declare our package

sub fooz {             # <--- Our target subroutine
    my $in = shift;    # passing the input
    return $in * 5;    # return value
}
1; # return value must be true
```

In main.pl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use bar;   # bar.pm must be in one path in @INC

my $foo = bar::fooz(12);  # calling fooz from our other perl script
print "Foo is $foo\n";
```

There is a lot more to learn, and I suggest you read up on the [documentation.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html)

Answer (score 4):

You want [IPC::System::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aSystem%3a%3aSimple)'s `capturex`.

```
use IPC::System::Simple qw( capturex );
my $output = capturex("perl", $path, $val1, $val2, @myarray);
```

It even handles errors for you.

Comment: Why the -1? The OP asked for a version of backticks where the command isn't subject to shell interpretation, and that's exactly what `capturex` is.

Answer (score 3):

The backticks simply work like a direct invocation one would make in a shell:

```
you@somewhere:~$ ./script.pl --key=value
```

Is basically the same as

```
my $returnval = `./script.pl --key=value`;
```

Comment: what do you mean with --key=value?

Comment: It was just an example for passing parameters. Replace it with anything applicable for your script; basically `$val1 $val2` ...

Answer (score 2):

For invoking other programs passing arguments and capturing output at the same time, I'm a big fan of [`IPC::Run`](https://metacpan.org/module/IPC%3a%3aRun):

```
use IPC::Run 'run';

my $exitcode = run [ $command, @args ], ">", \my $output;

# $exitcode contains the exit status and
# $output contains the command's STDOUT data
```

Comment: Instead of `IPC::Run`, `IPC::Cmd` provides similar functionality and is a core module.

Answer (score 1):

Does this not do what you want?

```
my $returnval = `$path $val1 $val2 @myarray`;
```

@Quentin however adds this useful advice:  If the value you want to pass is `foo "bar` then in shell you would have to do something like `"foo \"bar"`. Using extra arguments to system will take card of that for you. Using backticks won't; you need to construct the shell command you want manually.

Comment: It won't autoquote / escape the arguments

Comment: @Quentin:  Thank you for the advice.  I admit that I do not know what autoquoting is.  A quick grep through my Perl manpages turns up three, cryptic, passing references to "autoquoting" or "auto-quoting," but these do not explain; nor does a web search immediately turn up anything very informative.  If you can spare a moment, would you explain a bit further?  Thanks.

Comment: I tried that and after that i tried `$path /$val1 /$val2 /@myarray`, both didn't work :>

Comment: If the value you want to pass is `foo "bar` then in shell you would have to do something like `"foo \"bar"`. Using extra arguments to `system` will take card of that for you. Using backticks won't, you need to construct the shell command you want manually.

Comment: `$path \$val1 \$val2 \@myarray` works to call the function with the parameter. but the returned values seems not to fit. Do I have to write the return value into the exit funtion like: exit(value1); ?

Comment: @Quentin:  If I knew how, I would correct my answer and transfer it to your user-ID for reputational credit.  You are right, of course.  At any rate, I'll do what I can to correct my answer on your advice now.